# Q_PROPERTY NOTIFY signal and its argument

Tags: c++, qt, data-binding, binding, qml

I have the habit of writing my "propertyChanged" `signal`s with an argument, such that the receiving end doesn't need to call the `Q_PROPERTY`'s `READ` function explicitly.

I do this out of clarity and the assumption that in a QML data binding situation, no "expensive" call to the getter needs to be done to actually fetch the value, as it's already passed to QML as a signal argument.

My colleagues disagreed and said it was against "QML style", to which I responded the documentation clearly states it may have an argument that will take the new value of the underlying member:

> `NOTIFY` signals for `MEMBER` variables must take zero or one parameter, which must be of the same type as the property. The parameter will take the new value of the property.

Nowhere in the documentation is it stated that the QML binding system uses this parameter to prevent an additional function call to the getter when handling the signal. I understand this call will probably be made from C++, so no "expensive" QML to C++ call will be made, but it still is an extra function call, which in principle could result in a visible performance penalty in case of many updates.

I tried inspecting the QML binding source code, but couldn't infer anything from it. I wonder if someone knows what the deal is: is the signal argument used or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870182/for-a-notify-signal-on-a-property-what-difference-does-it-make-if-i-give-it-a-p/42870667#42870667

Comment: Please provide a (code) example that demonstrates the scenario you're curious about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the *values* of the changed *properties* in the `onPropertyChanged`-signal is, though possible, most surely not **the QML style**.

Would it be, then you should expect that at least for the basic types it is implemented, which is easily shown, it's not.

**basictypes.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 400; height: 450

    property int num: 5
    Button {
        text: num
        onClicked: num += 1
    }
    onNumChanged: console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments), arguments.length)
}
```

As you can see in the output, that there are no arguments passed, when you change even one of the most basic types, such as `int`.

If now QML would use the optional, but rarely implemented passed value *this* would create overhead, as you would always need to check the existence of the argument before using it. Though a simple check is not **to expensive**, if it usually evaluates to `false`, and then you use the workaround, why do it beforehand?

Though I might not rule out, that there are any passed values in any `onPropertyChanged`-signals in the official realse, there are none for properties added in QML with `property [type] [name]`. There also none for most inherited properties (tested the Button: `text`, `width`, `height`).

Comment: It is practically impossible to pass any `QObject` derived by value.

Comment: The "check if a value is passed" could be handled using templates and some SFINAE on the C++ side, which would incur no overhead.

Comment: @dtech, you are right, I err. There is a reference passed, to the object, the property points to.

Comment: @rubenvb: If you have everything precompiled, maybe. But if you push it to the JIT, I don't think so.

Answer (score 4):

> I wonder if someone knows what the deal is: is the signal argument used or not?

Here's one way to check:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QDebug>

class MyType : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool foo READ foo WRITE setFoo NOTIFY fooChanged)

public:
    MyType(QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QObject(parent),
        mFoo(0)
    {
    }

    bool foo() const
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
        return mFoo;
    }

    void setFoo(bool foo)
    {
        if (foo == mFoo)
            return;

        mFoo = foo;
        emit fooChanged(mFoo);
    }

signals:
    void fooChanged(bool foo);

private:
    bool mFoo;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<MyType>("App", 1, 0, "MyType");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

import App 1.0

Window {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Switch {
        id: fooSwitch
    }

    MyType {
        id: myType
        foo: fooSwitch.checked
        onFooChanged: print("onFooChanged, foo =", foo)
//        onFooChanged: print("onFooChanged myType.foo =", myType.foo)
    }
}
```

The output when switching back and forth is:

```
qml: onFooChanged, foo = true
qml: onFooChanged, foo = false
```

So it's safe to say that the value is used and not the getter.

To see what the output would have been like if the signal argument hadn't been used, uncomment the commented out line and comment out the other one:

```
bool __cdecl MyType::foo(void) const
qml: onFooChanged myType.foo = true
bool __cdecl MyType::foo(void) const
qml: onFooChanged myType.foo = false
```

Comment: I think you are looking at it the wrong way. You are attaching a handler to the signal directly, thus it uses the passed parameter. But that is not really a "binding situation". A binding situation would be when `myType.foo` is used in an binding expression. For example `property bool test: myType.foo && someOtherBool` - in that case when `foo` changes and the binding expression is reevaluated, it will not use the signal passed value but invoke the getter.

Comment: In `onFooChanged` the `foo` parameter shadows the `foo` property. Thus you are not invoking the property getter. Try `onFooChanged: print("onFooChanged, foo =", myType.foo)`. Obviously, I make a distinction between "binding" and "handler" - the handler gets access to the signal's parameters, if any, and you can have multiple. But that doesn't have any effects on how bindings are reevaluated when property values change.

Comment: You're right; I took the question to be about signal handlers, but now that I re-read it, I'm quite confused as to what they're asking. I think OP should provide some clarification with a code snippet. Also, the code you suggest in your second comment is already in the snippet, it's what the last part of the answer addresses.

Comment: Well, the OP reaffirms he isn't asking about handlers, but there is still some ambiguity. But at any rate, passing a parameter with the notification signal doesn't seem to have any benefits in the context of optimizing binding expressions evaluations . Your answer focuses on what I said in the linked answer - that emitting a value makes it easier to get to the value without having to reference the object and property getter, which mostly makes sense in C++, as there it is much harder to achieve an analog of what you do in QML via bindings. But that's generic signals, not strictly properties.

Answer (score 2):

> assumption that in a QML data binding situation, no "expensive" call
>   to the getter needs to be done to actually fetch the value, as it's
>   already passed to QML as a signal argument.

Technically speaking, it is not likely that there is anything similar to what you describe. It just doesn't make sense. If your getters are expensive, you should take care to cache the result in a simpler form, and either update on changes or on demand.

If QML bindings were exclusively single property to single property, such an optimization could make sense. But bindings in QML are actually anonymous expressions, and the way it works is when any change notification for an object that is referenced by the expression triggers its reevaluation. In such a case it would add needless complexity to the implementation, having one value sent from the notification signal to keep and others which you have to call getters for.

Obviously, I am just postulating here. Another thing that makes me skeptic of the existence of such an optimization is that the property binding system isn't all that sophisticated or focused on efficiency. Which is evident from the fact that it cannot even eliminate redundant evaluations in the case of property value inter-dependencies. I've seen claims that such optimizations exist, but I've tested and it failed to avoid even the most simple of binding tree redundancies.

Naturally, if you insist on `MEMBER` properties, this is not so easy to prove, since the getters are auto generated, and you don't get to insert your debug statement there.

But if you try it for a regular property, you will find out that even if the signal emits the actual value, the getter is invoked nonetheless. There is absolutely no reason why an auto-generated getter would get a different treatment.

As mentioned in the linked answer, if you need the value emitted for the C++ part of the code, then keep, it it will not interfere with the QML part. If not, then simply don't emit the value, even if minuscule, it is still overhead. Emitting the value is the C++ way, bindings are a fundamentally different concept that is not really applicable in C++ (not without extensive verbosity), the QML way does not require to emit the changed value.

So your are both wrong. It is not really "against the QML style", as it will not hinder anything, and having the option to emit a value in the documentation in no way suggest that it is "in line with the QML style", or that it gets any special treatment. So if that's the reason you are doing it, you might as well stop, as it is entirely redundant.

Comment: It's not so much the getter being expensive, it's the additional call of the getter from QML that would be the hypothetical "hotspot".

Comment: @rubenvb - based on the other answer, I think you should clarify what you mean by "QML data binding" - do you mean actual property bindings or do you mean signal handlers - the expressions which are attached to `onPropertyChanged`?

Comment: I mean data (property) binding: the same thing you get from using the QML Binding type. I am purely talking about the Q_PROPERTY related things.

Comment: @Drechterland the answer posted by Mitch seems to provide evidence to the contrary though.

Comment: See my commends below his answer. That is in case you are referring to me, I don't see any Drechterland here. In that answer, the property is never used in the context of a binding.

Comment: that Drechterland is my smartphone acting up. No idea where that came from either. I see what you're saying. Though I don't agree using `MyType.foo` will show what we need, instead the parameter name should be something different from `foo`, so that the debug output doesn't explicitly call the getter we're trying to detect calls into.

Comment: The answer that Mitch provides only proves that signal parameters can be used in the signal handler... which is... like... adoy :) His code doesn't have a binding situation, so I don't see how it could possibly establish anything about binding situations. If a property is used in a binding, and if that property changes, the binding reevaluation will invoke the getter regardless of whether the notification signal emits the property value or not. Test it if you don't trust me.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the code, generated in QtCreator by rightclicking on a property `foo` and selecting "Refactor/Generate Missing Q_PROPERTY Members"

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool foo READ foo NOTIFY fooChanged)
```

generates a signal containing the property

```
void fooChanged(bool foo);
```

So I would argue that this *is* the Qt/QML style

Comment: This was a great point.  That said, QtCreator actually does the exact *opposite* of this!  At least in Creator v.5.